# Why are Lists faster than character arrays for string concatenation

Tags: python, string

In the article linked below, the author compares the efficiency of different string concatenation methodologies in python:
http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

One thing that I did not understand is, why does method 3 (Mutable Character Arrays) result in a significantly slower performance than method 4 (joining a list of strings)

both of them are mutable and I would think that they should have comparable performance.

Comment: Presumably `array.fromstring` hasn't been optimized the way `str.join` has.

Comment: Also, note that this article is from 2004. Naive str appending is much faster in newer versions of Python, and so is `str.join`…

Comment: What @abarnert says is totally relevant. When that article was written, the latest version of Python was 2.3.3 (see http://www.python.org/download/releases/ and http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3.4/). Benchmarks done at that time are largely meaningless today.

Comment: Related: how does string concatenation compare between 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 -- unicode vs ascii?

Comment: @blakev: That's a tricky question, because how fast Unicode concatenation is in 3.3+ actually depends on what characters you have in the strings. So really, you need separate benchmarks for all the combinations of all-ASCII Unicode strings, all-UCS-2 Unicode strings, and general Unicode strings…

Comment: @blakev: But from a very quick test of `join` with an already-constructed list: `bytes` takes 1.0x as long in 3.3, `unicode` with all ASCII 0.5x, `unicode` with all UCS-2 0.8x, `unicode` with non-UCS-2 1.0x, `unicode` with mixed strings 1.05x.

Comment: Kind of surprising that for joining up completely-general Unicode strings, 3.3 is actually slightly slower than 2.7… but I guess the tradeoff of being twice as fast (and using 1/4th the memory) for a very common use case at the cost of being 5% slower (and still saving memory) in a pretty uncommon one is worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Both of them are mutable" is misleading you a bit.

It's true that in the list-append method, the *list* is mutable. But building up the list isn't the slow part. If you have 1000 strings of average length 1000, you're doing 1000000 mutations to the array, but only 1000 mutations to the list (plus 1000 increfs to string objects).

In particular, that means the `array` will have to spend 1000x as much time expanding (allocating new storage and copying the whole thing so far).

The slow part for the list method is the `str.join` call at the end. But that *isn't* mutable, and doesn't require any expanding. It uses two passes, to first calculate the size needed, then copy everything into it.

Also, that code inside `str.join` has had (and has continued to have since that article was written 9 years ago) a lot of work to optimize it, because it's a very common, and recommended, idiom that many real programs depend on every day; `array` has barely been touched since it was first added to the language.

But if you really want to understand the differences, you have to look at the source. In 2.7, the main work for the array method is in [`array_fromstring`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/arraymodule.c#l1375), while the main work for the list method is in [`string_join`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l1586). You can see how the latter takes advantage of the fact that we already know all of the strings we're going to be joining up at the start, while the former can't.

Comment: "It uses two passes, to first calculate the size needed, then copy everything into it." - really? Is that a list-specific optimization I wasn't aware of? It can't work for general iterables.

Comment: Ah, it makes a tuple out of the input if it's not already a tuple or list.

Comment: Your `bytes_join` link is broken. Try [`string_join`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l1586).

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks; I was looking at the 3.x code, and I thought I'd switched over to 2.7 and re-clicked the line, but obviously not… Anyway, `str.join` has had that optimization forever, which is why people are often surprised when they attempt to micro-optimize by passing it a genexpr instead of a listcomp and find that it's actually slightly slower…